# Localstorage selection Javascript - save style CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, local-storage

I want to make a drop down menu with three selections that change the color of the `nav` and saves it in local storage, when you update the page the color you picked is still there.

I want to do this in Javascript and not with any help from jQuery.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="box">
   <select>
      <option value="grey" id="grey">Grey</option>
      <option value="black" id="black">Black</option>
      <option value="green" id="green">Green</option>
   </select>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#box {
    height:50px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align: center; 
}
.grey {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-color: #FFF;
}
.black {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    color: #FFF;
}
.green {
    background-color: rgba(33.3, 46.7, 7.8);
    border-color: #000;
}
```

Here is my JS:

```
function setUp() {
   document.getElementById("grey").onclick = setSuccessStyle;
   document.getElementById("black").onclick = setErrorStyle;
   document.getElementById("green").onclick = setInfoStyle;
}

function setSuccessStyle() {
   var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
   messageBox.className = "grey";   
}

function setErrorStyle() {
   var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
   messageBox.className = "black";
}

function setInfoStyle() {
   var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
   messageBox.className = "green";
}
```

I know that I'm not supposed to have onclick as the "action" but I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Actually, for starters, you don't want to use `onclick`.  A better event to listen on in this case would be the `change` event, so `onchange`.  Also, you'll want to attach that listener to the `select` and check `this.value` when it triggers to see what color was selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of issues in your code.

Basically you need to use `onchange` on the `select` but not `click` on the `option`.

After the user pick a color, you store it in the [`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). When the page load, you read it from the `localStorage` and set the class with it value.

This snippet will not work because of security reason so you can see the result in this [bin](http://output.jsbin.com/xenoso)

```js
function setUp(sel) {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
  messageBox.className = sel.value;
  localStorage.setItem('color', sel.value);
}

var selectElm = document.querySelector('select');
selectElm.value = localStorage.getItem('color') || selectElm.querySelector('option').getAttribute('value');
selectElm.onchange();
```

```css
#box{
  height:50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align: center; 
}
.grey {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: #FFF;
}
.black {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #FFF;
}
.green {
  background-color: rgba(0, 72, 3, 0.47);
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="box">
  <select onchange="setUp(this)">
    <option value="grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
  </select>
</nav>
```

Comment: Very nice and compact solution.  Was going to post about the editor disallowing the local storage access, but you've edited your answer.  You might consider swapping it out for simple code blocks in the answer, but that's up to your preference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just realized that I didn't explain my answer so I was edited it. In the snippet you can't see the `localStorage` functionality but you can see the effect of the `change` event. Also, I like to use the snippet because the code in snippet more organized.

Comment: If you don't mind my suggesting so, you can also remove the `(this)` part of `setUp` function.  It's redundant in this case and `setUp` is never called with the param, so you can use `this` inside of `setUp` instead.  I made a fork of the jsbin if you want to take a quick glance.  I also moved the `onchange` out of the markup and into the javascript itself.  All very minor and only suggestions, but I thought I'd share them anyway. http://jsbin.com/dozubucuna/1/edit?html,js

Comment: Thanks guys! I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" all the time. I don't know whats wrong, it worked for a while but then I got this error again.

Comment: What did you do before this error start to shown? Did you moved the script into the `head` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setUp() {
  document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", onChangeSelect);
}

function onChangeSelect() {
  var value = document.getElementById("select").value;
  console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case "grey":
      setSuccessStyle();
      break;
    case "black":
      setErrorStyle();
      break;
    case "green":
      setInfoStyle();
      break;
  }
}

function setSuccessStyle() {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
  messageBox.className = "grey"; 
}

function setErrorStyle() {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
  messageBox.className = "black";
}

function setInfoStyle() {
  var messageBox = document.getElementById("box");
  messageBox.className = "green";
}

setUp();
```

```css
#box{
  height:50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align: center; 
}
.grey {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: #FFF;
}
.black {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #FFF;
}
.green {
  background-color: rgba(33.3, 46.7, 7.8);
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="box">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="grey" id="grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="black" id="black">Black</option>
    <option value="green" id="green">Green</option>
  </select>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses your HTML and CSS as-is. Just replace your setUp function with this and make sure to call setUp on page load.

```
function setUp() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box").getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    box.onchange = function(){
            switch(this.value){
                case 'grey':
                    setSuccessStyle();
                    break;
                case 'black':
                    setErrorStyle();
                    break;
                case 'green':
                default:
                    setInfoStyle();
                    break;
            }
            //localStorage part
            localStorage.setItem("box",this.value);     //'box' can be any string key you want
        };
    //load the old value from localStorage
    var selection = localStorage.getItem("box");
    if(selection !== null){
        var items = box.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].value == selection){
                box.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```